# Changing gmock expectation

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mockito, googlemock

I have a unit test I want to write in GMock.  However, my familiarity is primarily with Mockito.  What I would write in Mockito is:

```
Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.never()).someFunctionCall(Matchers.<String>any());
doSomething(mock);
Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.times(1)).someFunctionCall(Matchers.<String>any());
doSomethingElse(mock);
```

Which corresponds to verifying that `doSomething` never invokes `someFunctionCall` but is called exactly once by `doSomethingElse`.

How would I accomplish the same thing with GMock?

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock, someFunctionCall(_)).Times(0);
doSomething(mock);
EXPECT_CALL(mock, someFunctionCall(_)).Times(1);
doSomethingElse(mock);
```

Obviously doesn't work since the expectations stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mock::VerifyAndClearExpectations / Mock::VerifyAndClear can be used for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For something like that, you'd probably want to set up two distinct tests. One for `doSomething`, and one for `doSomethingElse`. Alternately, if the behavior of the second depends on the first, you could do something like:

```
{
  MyMock mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, someFunctionCall(_)).Times(0);
  doSomething(mock);
}
{
  MyMock mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, someFunctionCall(_)).Times(1);
  doSomethingElse(mock);
}
```

The verification of the assertions is done on object destruction, so scoping each mock to just the set of calls that it's needed for will validate the assertions. But really, I'd probably try to separate the testing of the two methods into separate tests. If you have boilerplate setup that you don't want to repeat, stick it in the base class that your `TEST_F`s derive from.

Comment: Neither case is really feasible given the surrounding case.

Comment: Is it possible to share more of the context around the code - it would be easier to give an answer with more info, though I see you found something that works too. The fact that there's some tight coupling between how the methods need to be called makes me think that something about the general design isn't as clear as it should be.